# Split using JQuery - Loop through the String

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a string as follows

```
var str = "foobar~~some example text~~this is a string, foobar1~~some example 
text1~~this is a string1";
```

I need to loop through this string and get the text "some example text", "some example text1"

Can any one let me know how to loop through this.

Comment: Please a) format the question b) show what you've tried

Comment: You want to check if the search text is present or you want its position in string?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, any example please...

Answer (score 2):

You may use [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with the following regex:

```
/~~[^~]+~~/g
```

In order to loop you may use [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on resulting array:

```
reatVal.forEach(function(ele, idx) {
    console.log('element n.: ' + idx + ' value: ' + ele)
})
```

```js
var str = "foobar~~some example text~~this is a string, foobar1~~some example text1~~this is a string1";
var retVal = str.match(/~~[^~]+~~/g).map(function(ele, idx) {
    return ele.replace(/~~/g, '');
});


console.log('retVal is the following array: ' + retVal);

retVal.forEach(function(ele, idx) {
    console.log('element n.: ' + idx + ' value: ' + ele)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the use of capturing groups and a bit of helper methods:

```js
String.prototype.getCapturingGroups = function(re){
  if(re instanceof RegExp){
    let groups_contents = [];
    this.replace(re, function(str, match){
      groups_contents.push(match);
    });
    return groups_contents;
  }
  return [];
}

var str = "foobar~~some example text~~this is a string, foobar1~~some example text1~~this is a string1";
var regex = /\~\~([^~]+)\~\~/g;
var content_arr = str.getCapturingGroups(regex);

content_arr.forEach((e,i)=>console.log(`n°${i} is : ${e}`))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and got it done.

```
var arr = str.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var onetext = arr[i];
        var twotext = onetext.split('~~');
        for (var j =0; j< twotext.length; j++) {
            console.log(twotext[j]);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for all your quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var str = "foobar~~some example text~~this is a string, 
foobar1~~some example text1~~this is a string1";
    var strArr = str.split(',');
    var finalStrArr = []; 
    for(var i=0; i<strArr.length; i++) { 
        var finalStr = strArr[i].split('~~'); 
        finalStrArr.push(finalStr[1]); 
    };
```

This code will work only if the string comes only in that format. I mean the above code will give you the 1st string after the characters ~~.
I put `finalStrArr.push(finalStr[1]);` I am getting the index of 1 because I am assuming that the expected string will always be in that position.