# Split and find the value exists using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, split

I have an array like

```
[test1^^^68936^^^2017-06-05^^^274^^^NO^^^location1^^^1840, test2^^^68766^^^2016-06-05^^^274^^^NO^^^location2^^^1840,test3^^^68966^^^2017-06-05^^^274^^^YES^^^location1^^^1840]
```

where I need to split it and find out whether the fourth key in that array of keys has NO or YES or 1. If both NO and YES exists in an array, I need to alert the user that they have both of them in it.

please let me know how to do it in JavaScript.

Comment: Apart from you showing absolute no effort whatsoever, this does not seem to be that much different from your previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46013087/split-using-jquery-loop-through-the-string

Comment: Kiran was the answer helpful? Please respond

Comment: @AKA, I have used your part of code and finished it. My code is pasted in the comments. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without `split()` also:

```js
var array = ['test1^^^68936^^^2017-06-05^^^274^^^NO^^^location1^^^1840', 'test2^^^68766^^^2016-06-05^^^274^^^NO^^^location2^^^1840','test3^^^68966^^^2017-06-05^^^274^^^YES^^^location1^^^1840'];

var arrayStr = array.toString();
if(arrayStr.indexOf('^^^YES') !== -1 && arrayStr.indexOf('^^^NO') !== -1){
  alert('You have both of them in it');
}else{
   alert('You do not have both of them in it');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your array contains strings

```
["test1^^^68936^^^2017-06-05^^^274^^^NO^^^location1^^^1840", "test2^^^68766^^^2016-06-05^^^274^^^NO^^^location2^^^1840","test3^^^68966^^^2017-06-05^^^274^^^YES^^^location1^^^1840"]
```

You can get the YES/NO keys by mapping the array and splitting it like this

```
["test1^^^68936^^^2017-06-05^^^274^^^NO^^^location1^^^1840", "test2^^^68766^^^2016-06-05^^^274^^^NO^^^location2^^^1840","test3^^^68966^^^2017-06-05^^^274^^^YES^^^location1^^^1840"].map(function(str){return str.split("^^^")[4]})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
res = arr.join("").match(/NO|YES/g)
if(res.includes("YES") && res.includes("NO")){
  console.log("Both present")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried and got solved

```
var arrayStr = myarray.toString();
var stringExists = [];

if(arrayStr.indexOf('^^^NO^^^') !== -1) {
    stringExists.push('0');
}
if(arrayStr.indexOf('^^^YES^^^') !== -1) {
    stringExists.push('1');
}

if (stringExists.length > 1) {
    alert("Error");
    return;
}
```

Thanks for all your support guys..